# Generate Random Post Links Somewhere in the post

Tags: links

I have a little probleme on which I really need help :( . So, I need to create in my **wordpress' post** something that I call "You may also like to read"! Let me tell you more about this:

For example, my wordpress post is something like this:

Title.

3-4 lines of text (like an introduction ~ theme of the article).

You may also like to read.

The rest of the post.

End.

The "You may also like to read" contain 2 links. Im alwas generate these links manually via html code (ul, li, a tags). So it's difficult to me to always generate these links manually. I need somehow to generate these links randomely and automatically.

[image]

I googled for 2h and I found nothing, actually I found a plugin that can do that but it's not working (no update for more than 4 years).... I found also some php code but neither that works. So I really have no idea what I could do next :(

So can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with `WP_Query`.  You say that you want to show two link randomly, presumably these are Posts and there is no specific criteria such as category or date range that need be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

**You have indicated that you wish to reuse this code, so it is better used within a function so that it can be called whenever you desire. I've made changes to my answer to reflect this below.**

---

You can use the below code to generate a list of posts (in you case 2x random posts) together with a header. The output is formated in a way indicated by the image in your question.  This code can be used anywhere within your theme -

```
my_post_list();
```

The function that does all of the work, below, should be placed in **functions.php**.

If you wish, you can pass a different list title to the function, as well as a different `$args` array. This allows you to customise the scope of your random Posts, targeting specific categories or tags, only searching a certain date range, or only looking for Posts where some custom data value is set for example - the possibilities are endless.  Check out the [Class Reference for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more information on what you can do with these args.

```
/**
 * Output a list of posts under a heading
 *
 * @param string $title The title to output in the list heading
 * @param array $args   The arguments for getting the required posts
 */
function my_post_list($title = 'You may also like to read:', $args = array()){

    $defaults = array(  // Set some defaults for querying the Posts
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
        'posts_per_page'        => 2,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'orderby'               => 'rand'
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);    // Parse any arguments passed to this function with the defaults to create a final '$args' array
    
    $random = new WP_Query($args);  // Query the Posts
    
    if($random->have_posts()) : // Check to make sure some random Posts were returned
    
        echo '<h4>' . $title . '</h4>';
        echo '<ul>';
        
        while($random->have_posts()) : $random->the_post(); // Create a new custom Loop, and for each Post set up the postdata
    
            printf('<li id="random-post-%1$s">', get_the_ID());
            
            printf(
                '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                get_permalink(get_the_ID()),
                the_title_attribute('before=Check out \'&after=\'&echo=0'),
                get_the_title()
            );
            
            echo '</li>';
            
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();    // Reset the postdata so that the rest of your Loop will work correctly
        
        echo '</ul>';
        
    endif;
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Im novice in php coding (but Im good on html, css and a little jquery). So where I will put this code ? If I put it in the "post section", wordpress will not excute it  :( <br/> Can you pls be more specific ? :( <br/>thanks

Comment: This is replacing the code that you use to manually generate the random links, so it should go in the same place.  Make sure that you wrap the code in PHP tags **if necessary** - `<?php` before the code and `?>` after the code

Comment: thanks alot for your reply, I succeeded. I have only one question: Everytime I put this "You May Also Like To Read:" I need to put all your code down. How I can Put this "You May Also Like To Read:" without putting your entire code everytime. Something like "id" and"class" for html which with them we costumize them with css. Thanks again for your help

Comment: See my edit, hopefullt that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Wow Thanks you so muchhhhhh .... I'm really grateful

Comment: You're welcome.  Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted and maybe even upvote if you found it helpful.

Comment: @Fantastickmath if you lack the knowledge to understand the answer, perhaps you should hire a developer to do the final step of work, David isn't here to teach basic PHP skills, and it's unfair to ask him to expand his answer so broadly

Comment: Also, what you've said in the comment section implies you have a plugin that lets you put PHP inside your content editor. ***This would be incredibly dangerous and insecure***

Comment: Yes I used a plugin to insert php in the post section.... I really didn't find any other solution to try. :( .... Ragarding to MR David, Im really grateful for his work and his help.

Comment: Must have been a long week, I didn't pick up on you using code in the editor at all!  As @TomJNowell says, that is really not a good idea and you should start looking at ways around that.  I'd suggest you start by looking into [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), or at worst editing directly the templates within your theme current theme - the code in my answer will work in the same way.  Just don't forget to take backups ;-)

Comment: A fuller technical solution would involve either a short code or modifying the post content using the 'the_content' filter